# How do I fetch a branch on someone else's fork on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-fork, git-fetch

I've forked from a repo on GitHub. I want to get the code from a branch on another user's fork.

Must I clone this user's whole repo to a separate local repo or can I do something like `git checkout link_to_the_other_users_branch`?

Comment: You're looking for git "remotes": http://progit.org/book/ch2-5.html

Answer (score 384, accepted):

```
$ git remote add theirusername git@github.com:theirusername/reponame.git
$ git fetch theirusername
$ git checkout -b mynamefortheirbranch theirusername/theirbranch
```

Note that there are multiple "correct" URIs you can use for the remote when you add it in the first step.

- `git@github.com:theirusername/reponame.git` is an SSH-based URI
- `https://github.com/theirusername/reponame.git` is an HTTPS URI

Which one you prefer to use will depend on your situation. GitHub has a help article explaining the difference and helping you choose: [Choosing a URL for your remote repository](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#choosing-a-url-for-your-remote-repository)

Comment: What does that last line do?

Comment: The last line checks out a new branch called `mynamefortheirbranch` with its start point set to the head of `theirusername/theirbranch`.

Comment: I get *Fatal: cannot update paths and switch to branch 'xyz' at the same time. Did you intend to checkout 'xyz/xyz' which can not be resolved as commit?*

Comment: Did not work with me.

Comment: @amalloy It is creating a branch as expected but not allowing to push the branch in my current fork. Getting this message "  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push krupa-fork HEAD:develop

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push krupa-fork HEAD"

Comment: after the first command of adding remote-
``$ git fetch theirusername theirbranchname:yourbranchname``
and the branch will be fetched and added to your local forked repo. Then do the push if needed.

Answer (score 48):

[amalloy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9153737) didn't work for me. This did:

```
git remote add theirusername https://github.com/theirusername/reponame
git fetch theirusername
git checkout -b mynamefortheirbranch theirusername/theirbranch
```

Resources:

- https://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html
- http://crunchify.com/how-to-fork-github-repository-create-pull-request-and-merge/

Comment: I believe you are missing a `.git` at the end of your first line.

Comment: @TomNorway Are you sure? Doesn't it work for you like this?

Comment: @TomNorway I tested it and it works without the `.git` extension. Do you use GitHub?

Comment: I do indeed. I must admit that I didn't test it - my mistake. I only tested with .git, which I assumed was required.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - `git fetch theirusername` returns `fatal: 'username' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: @anks Your error message looks weird.

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski yeah, well, I used the first command incorrectly (missed the theirusername after add). sorry :)