# With Bitbucket how do I merge in a pull request into my local branch so I can test it before merging into master

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have an opensrc project on bitbucket- https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/jaudiotagger/src/master/README.md

I have some pull requests by contributors to review.

In the past I have just checked the code and then merged the code into the remote master branch on Bitbucket using the Merge button. But these pull requests are too complex for that I need to merge with my local master branch on my computer, build and test it, and then only if okay merge it into the remote master branch.

But I dont know how to do this ?

Comment: Do you have access to their branch?

Comment: You know the name of the pull request branch, right? So fetch it and merge it and test it.

Comment: @matt I need you to break that down for me

Comment: Just like https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/resolve-merge-conflicts/ except that there isn't any merge conflict to resolve, you're merging in order to test locally.

Comment: i cant follow that, too general. if you write me an answer I can use I will give you a 100 bounty

Comment: tried git checkout mvmn/generics_refactoring didnt recognize it

Comment: the git commands are so unituitive once you get away from commit, push and pull

Comment: The problem is that the branch you want to merge is not in *your* repository at all yet; it's only in the contributor's fork. You'll need to add that repository as another remote, and *then* you fetch the branch and merge your master in to the branch for testing.

Comment: @chepner thanks i think your right conceptually, the link matt gave doesn't have that at all. But isn't it possible for someone to list the full set of commands in an answer

Comment: @PaulTaylor yes it does, I presume this is a forked repo and the link has a section "Resolving the conflict between Git forks"

Comment: @matt there is nothing in there about setting up a remote which it seems i have do according to everyone else

Comment: No, because they assume you can access the forked repo on Bitbucket directly, in your browser. And that seems like a perfectly reasonable assumption.

Comment: and can I ? - no idea what that means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another approach. I cloned their repository and then checkedout a remote branch locally

```
git clone https://ijabz@bitbucket.org/mvmn/jaudiotagger.git
git checkout origin/generics_refactoring
```

Then I can test their new code, and view it in my IDE

Then if it is okay I can approve the request on BitBucket and that will handle any merge conflict problems (although there arent any in this case), and I can just delete the cloned repository as I no longer need it.

This may not seem the most elegant solution but at least I just about understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The branch you want to merge *isn't* part of your repository yet; it's only in the contributors repository. You'll need to create a new remote first.

```
git remote add mvmn ... # You'll need the contributor's fork's URL
git remote update mvmn
git checkout -b pr69 --track mvmn/generics_refactoring
git merge master
```

After you are done testing, you can delete the `generics_refactoring` branch (after checking out another branch, of course)

```
git branch -D pr69
```

Comment: thanks, looks right but I tried git add remote mvmn https://ijabz@bitbucket.org/mvmn/jaudiotagger.git and that failed, so not sure what fork url is

Comment: Try `git@bitbucket.org:mvmn/jaudiotagger.git`.

Comment: the problem was your command is wrong way round, it should be git remote add not git add remote

Comment: Ive done all four vcommands but I dont seem to have the actual changes from the branch ?

Answer (score 0):

Whoever did the pull request has the changes in one branch `feature`, for example. If you can do `git fetch <your remote>`, then the branch `feature` will be available for you. Now, you should run `git checkout <your master branch>`, just in case you are not there, then run `git merge feature`.

With that done you should be able to run your tests locally before merging the feature branch in your remote master

Comment: I want to check https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/jaudiotagger/pull-requests/69 so tried git fetch mvmn/generics_refactoring it gave error for me ?

Comment: if you run `git fetch <your_remote>` and then run `git branch -a`, can you see `generics_refactoring`?

Comment: if you can't see it, try [fetching from someone's fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153598/how-do-i-fetch-a-branch-on-someone-elses-fork-on-github)

Comment: when you say <your remote> im not entirely sure what the value is meant to be, i assume it was the name of the user/brach i was interested in, but maybe it is isnt.

Comment: I mean something like `origin`, what is the output of `git remote show`?

Comment: ive upated question with output